# simulate a mouse-click without moving cursor

Tags: python, winapi, automation, mouseevent, sendmessage

I'm looking to create a bot for a game I play, where he also created a bot by another company where he does things in background mode and without moving the user's cursor, so he tried to use their same method, in this case, a " bot vision" and click background on it

```
import win32gui, win32api, win32con

def click_game_window():
    game_window_name = 'GAME'
    game_hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, game_window_name)
    
    click(game_hwnd)
    
def click(hwnd):
    lParam = win32api.MAKELONG(935, 821)
    win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, lParam)
    win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, None, lParam)
```

so I did that, but it is not clicking in the game, I tested it in other windows like NOTEPAD, but it still didn't work, anyone can help me, PLEASE?

Comment: why was OpenCV tagged? this has got nothing to do with computer vision.

Comment: how not? I explained that I want to make a "bot vision" with opencv, and click directly on it

Comment: I see. but please review [mre]. knowing where you're going is _good to know_, but in _this specific issue_ (creating mouse button events), OpenCV plays no role at all. it's very much a WinAPI question.